# jenkins is slow resopnding to main page request

Tags: performance, jenkins

I am using jenkins from war in version 1.491.
When I try to load the main page it is very slow.
It started after upgrade from version 1.482.

I tried kill -3 and saw that:

Handling GET / : RequestHandlerThread[#14]" daemon prio=10 tid=0x08c92800 nid=0x2ea6 runnable [0x9f9f3000..0x9f9f5e50]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at java.io.UnixFileSystem.getBooleanAttributes0(Native Method)
        at java.io.UnixFileSystem.getBooleanAttributes(UnixFileSystem.java:228)
        at java.io.File.isDirectory(File.java:754)
        at jenkins.model.lazy.AbstractLazyLoadRunMap.load(AbstractLazyLoadRunMap.java:599)
        at jenkins.model.lazy.AbstractLazyLoadRunMap.search(AbstractLazyLoadRunMap.java:344)
        at hudson.model.AbstractBuild.getPreviousBuild(AbstractBuild.java:207)
        at hudson.model.AbstractBuild.getPreviousBuild(AbstractBuild.java:100)
        at hudson.model.Job.getLastFailedBuild(Job.java:824)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor42.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.commons.jexl.util.PropertyExecutor.execute(PropertyExecutor.java:125)
        at org.apache.commons.jexl.util.introspection.UberspectImpl$VelGetterImpl.invoke(UberspectImpl.java:314)
        at org.apache.commons.jexl.parser.ASTArrayAccess.evaluateExpr(ASTArrayAccess.java:185)
        at org.apache.commons.jexl.parser.ASTIdentifier.execute(ASTIdentifier.java:75)
        at org.apache.commons.jexl.parser.ASTReference.execute(ASTReference.java:83)
        at org.apache.commons.jexl.parser.ASTReference.value(ASTReference.java:57)
        at org.apache.commons.jexl.parser.ASTReferenceExpression.value(ASTReferenceExpression.java:51)
        at org.apache.commons.jexl.ExpressionImpl.evaluate(ExpressionImpl.java:80)
        at hudson.ExpressionFactory2$JexlExpression.evaluate(ExpressionFactory2.java:72)
        at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.CoreTagLibrary$3.run(CoreTagLibrary.java:134)
        at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
        at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.CoreTagLibrary$2.run(CoreTagLibrary.java:105)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.JellyViewScript.run(JellyViewScript.java:81)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.IncludeTag.doTag(IncludeTag.java:146)
        at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.TagScript.run(TagScript.java:269)
        at org.apache.commons.jelly.TagSupport.invokeBody(TagSupport.java:161)
        at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.ForEachTag.doTag(ForEachTag.java:150)
        at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.TagScript.run(TagScript.java:269)
        at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.ReallyStaticTagLibrary$1.run(ReallyStaticTagLibrary.java:99)
        at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.CoreTagLibrary$2.run(CoreTagLibrary.java:105)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.CallTagLibScript.run(CallTagLibScript.java:119)
        at org.apache.commons.jelly.TagSupport.invokeBody(TagSupport.java:161)
        at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.ForEachTag.doTag(ForEachTag.java:150)
        at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.TagScript.run(TagScript.java:269)
        at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.ReallyStaticTagLibrary$1.run(ReallyStaticTagLibrary.java:99)
        at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
        at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.CoreTagLibrary$1.run(CoreTagLibrary.java:98)
        at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.ReallyStaticTagLibrary$1.run(ReallyStaticTagLibrary.java:99)
        at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
        at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.CoreTagLibrary$2.run(CoreTagLibrary.java:105)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.CallTagLibScript.run(CallTagLibScript.java:119)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.groovy.JellyBuilder.doInvokeMethod(JellyBuilder.java:283)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.groovy.Namespace$ProxyImpl.invoke(Namespace.java:92)
        at $Proxy32.projectView(Unknown Source)
        at lib.JenkinsTagLib$projectView.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:42)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:120)
        at hudson.model.View.main.run(main.groovy:14)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.groovy.GroovierJellyScript.run(GroovierJellyScript.java:66)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.groovy.GroovierJellyScript.run(GroovierJellyScript.java:59)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.IncludeTag.doTag(IncludeTag.java:146)
        at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.TagScript.run(TagScript.java:269)
        at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)

Any help appreciated.

P.S. - also asked at jenkins dev group: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/jenkinsci-dev/DJpaLTEsJ-I

Answer (score 1):

Also resulted in a bug being raised: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-16089 Still waiting for it to be resolved