# Unusably slow Jenkins: Normal CPU but high disk activity on Jenkins web page access

Tags: performance, jenkins

On Jenkins v1.528, after a few hundred builds, web page access and build job completion slows to many times slower than normal, all the way to unusable.  Restart fixes the issue.  The host machine,  a Mac circa 2012, has gigabytes of available memory and CPU usage is normal.

But I notice a persistent spike in disk usage when accessing a Jenkins web page (such as one for a Jenkins job/task/build).  It seems that Jenkins has possibly run out of heap space.  Yet I can't think of anything that has changed on this Jenkins instance or on the host machine to cause the issue (it didn't used to be a problem).

Also, I've seen some fixes for major slowness recently, but they went into prior versions.

Comment: could you fix your issue?

Comment: Iirc, setting the jvm heap size to a higher limit worked.  Yet I am still not sure why it used so much memory.  It may be a bug in that version of Jenkins.

Answer (score 1):

We have a similar issue after restart. This is what I figured our still today.

Your issue seems to be related to this issues:

[jenkins is slow resopnding to main page request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13475955/jenkins-is-slow-resopnding-to-main-page-request)

[Jenkins gets very slow after saving some Jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23651272/jenkins-gets-very-slow-after-saving-some-jobs)

[Jenkins' homepage loading very slowly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22062357/jenkins-homepage-loading-very-slowly)

[Jenkins is very slow on first visit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29252603/jenkins-is-very-slow-on-first-visit)