# Jenkins gets very slow after saving some Jobs

Tags: jenkins

i know there are several issues with a topic close to this one. But as fas as I searched i did not found a thread/question with the same topic.

So here is the situation:
On our Jenkins Server we a many build jobs (maybe a few hundred). Some of them running on Slaves, some on the master. Now i was asked to change settings of some of them (lets say 50), so the have project based security and I had to change the slave server they are running on. Before they ran already on a Slave, but a different one.

The Problem:
In the beginning everything went fine. I changed the settings ob several jobs quick and startet to change the settings of the next job. But after some time the configuration settings began to load slower and slower. First it were a few secounds(after 10 Job), then a few more secounds (after 20 jobs), then like one minute (after 30 jobs) and now several minutes (after 40 jobs). I open every settings page in a new tap and close the tab once I finished my configurations.

My Question:
Why does it take Jenkins so long to open up the configuration page? Especially because in the beginning there was nearly no loading tim and now after I changed a few jobs i have to wait minutes for it. What could be the reason?

Answer (score 1):

You need to see in the first step what is configuration of this new slave,
Issue can be memory based, so on master instance check the memory usage and check the java process, can be done with `strace -p <PID>` depends on your environment.
Instance can be slower due to memmory usage which is in the most cases.

Comment: Just updated all plugins -> it did not help. BUT I think i found the reason: i have uninstalled the Plugin „Publish over SSH“ and it helped for now. System update will be done soon too. Thank you for your help. :)

Comment: deinstalltion did not help after all. Server went back to be slow. Updated now my Jenkins Server to the latest version.